# How to make a list out of a BS4 output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this code right now:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

get = requests.get("https://solmfers-minting-site.netlify.app/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(get.text, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('script'):
    print(i.get('src'))
```

And I need to somehow turn the output into a list and remove the `None` values from it since it outputs it like this:

```
jquery.js
nicepage.js
None
None
/static/js/2.c20455e8.chunk.js
/static/js/main.87864e1d.chunk.js
```

Comment: Removed the `image` and formated the `output`, cause it always is a better idea to present your data as text, so it is easier to copy. You may like to take a minute and read about [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append your extracted values to a list.

```
result = []
for i in soup.find_all('script'):
    elem = i.get('src')
    if elem is not None:
        result.append(elem)
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
result = [x['src'] for x in soup.find_all('script') if x.get('src') is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your near to your goal, but select your elements more specific and append the `src` to a list while iterating your `ResultSet`:

```
data = []

for i in soup.find_all('script', src=True):
    data.append(i.get('src'))
```

Alternative with `css selectors`:

```
for i in soup.select('script[src]'):
    data.append(i.get('src'))
```

And as allready mentioned with `list comprehension`:

```
[i.get('src') for i in soup.select('script[src]')]
```

#### Output

```
['jquery.js', 'nicepage.js', '/static/js/2.c20455e8.chunk.js', '/static/js/main.87864e1d.chunk.js']
```